Taking input from turtle module in python
import turtle as tu

turtle = tu.Turtle()
turtle.color("cyan1")
turtle.shape("turtle")
square_len = tu.textinput("Square Lenght", "Lenght") 
def draw_square():
    turtle.forward(square_len)
    turtle.right(square_len)
    turtle.right(square_len)
    turtle.right(square_len)

draw_square()
screen = tu.Screen()
screen.exitonclick()

I get this error when I run the program
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Hp\Desktop\Codes\temp.py", line 6, in <module>
    square_len = turtle.textinput("Square Lenght", "Lenght")   
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'textinput' 

I want to take input from user

square_len
then draw a square with it


What version of Python are you using? Works for me fine on 3.12.3.

Try using tu.numinput instead and see if you get the same error. Also don't name your object turtle, which is same as the module name turtle. Change that to t or something.

i get this different error: Exception has occurred: TypeError can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'...

Incorporating @NYCCoder's numinput() suggestion, passing angles to right() instead of distances, and not mixing the object oriented turtle API with the turtle functional API, we get something like:
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def draw_square(length):
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.right(90)  # orient turtle back to where it started

screen = Screen()
square_length = screen.numinput("Square Length", "Length")

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.color("cyan1")
turtle.shape("turtle")

draw_square(square_length)

screen.exitonclick()


A good effort (note the spelling of length).
You just need two things:

You need to convert the input to float, that was a cause of the only error I saw.
forward and right turns * 4

Here is the code:
import turtle as tu

turtle = tu.Turtle()
turtle.color("cyan1")
turtle.shape("turtle")
square_len = float(tu.textinput("Square Lenght", "Lenght")) 
def draw_square():
    turtle.forward(square_len)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(square_len)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(square_len)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(square_len)


draw_square()
screen = tu.Screen()
screen.exitonclick()


I use python version 3.12 for the above.
The result looks like this:

